# spark streaming with saveastextfile giving mismatch record count

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

i am reading data from kinesis stream and then just store into HDFS using saveastextfile command. I got the output records but count was mismatch. Total input record count is 1000 and expecting the same in output. But always it written less than 100.

```
splitCSV.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction2<JavaRDD<String[]>,Time>()
{
public void call(JavaRDD<String[]> rdd, Time time) throws Exception 
{
...

}
...saveAsTextFile("/Selva")

}
```

Comment: better block code format

Comment: How are you counting input? That 'saveAsTextFile' is called on the RDD or the DStream?

Comment: I don't have enough info to give you a definitive answer, but I tell you what I guess that's going on:  You are using `rdd.saveAsTextFile(...)` for each RDD in the stream, effectively overwriting the previous data every time.